# Polynomial roots property

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $P$ be a $n$-degree real polynomial having $n$ simple roots $x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n$.

The problem asks to prove that

$$ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{P''(x_k)}{P'(x_k)} =0$$

I tried writing $P$ as the product of $x−x_i$ and differentiating it twice but the calculations are too hard to carry out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried writing $P$ as the product of $x-x_i$ and differentiating it twice but the calculations are too hard to carry out

Comment: @ahmed Can you differentiate it once?  Notice how simple $P’$ looks when you evaluate it at an $x_i$.  Can you see a way to simplify $P’’$ also?  (it will probably still have about $n$ terms but it’s manageable)

Answer (score 0):

An example :

Let
$$P(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)$$
Then
$$P'(x)=1.(x+1).(x-2)+(x-1).1.(x-2)+(x-1).(x+1).1$$
and
$$P''(x)=1.1.(x-2)+1.(x+1).1+1.1.(x-2)+(x-1).1.1+1.(x+1).1+(x-1).1.1$$
$$P''(x)=2 [(x-1)+(x+1)+(x-2)]$$
$$P''(1)=2[2-1] =2 : P''(-1)=2[-2-3]=-10 : P''(2)=2[1+3]=8$$
And
$$2-10+8=0$$
So, now it's about generalising this process...